# using ffmpeg with python, Input buffer exhausted before END element found

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

When I run this from command line everything is fine

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 320000 -vn output.mp3
```

But when I call the same from python

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp4', '-f', 'mp3', '-ab', '320000', '-vn', 'output.mp3'])
```

After several seconds converting I'm getting this error

```
[aac @ 0x7fb3d803e000] decode_band_types: Input buffer exhausted before 
END element found
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing 
input
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fb3d8000000] stream 1, offset 0x80011d: 
partial file
input.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-dn` & `-ignore_unknown` and `-sn` option (if subtitles causing encoding failure).

`-dn` refers to no data encoding.

`-sn` refers to no subtitles encoding

`-ignore_unknown` refers to ignore the unknown streams(SCTE 35, 128 data)

Irrespective of the input streams, `-dn` `-sn` & `-ignore_unknown` options will work.

That will solve your problem.

There are another options if you want to preserve the data, subtitles streams.

`-c:d copy` refers to copy the data streams.

`-c:s copy` refers to copy the subtitle streams.

You can use `-copy_unknown` option to get the unknown streams into your output.

Your final code would look like below.

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp4', '-f', 'mp3', '-ab', '320000', '-vn', '-sn', '-dn', '-ignore_unknown', 'output.mp3'])
```

NOTE: `-copy_unknown` option only works with ffmpeg 4.x version or above.

Answer (score 1):

Note - this error is not a FATAL error as defined by ffmpeg, meaning you could catch the error in code and the conversion will continue and the mp4 will be playable. It will be missing the 'failed' information, but most likely this was invisible to the user.

Comment: To improve your answer please add the respective code.